# Figuring out OOP in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop

I am new to AS3 and OOP concepts. I have one class called AlienShips

I have a laser beam and I am trying to check collision of beam with all the alienships on my stage. But collision gives weird results.. it detects all the alienships and not just one specific ship. So when my beam hits one of the alienships it destroys all the rest of the ships as well.

Here is the code of my AlienShip

```
public class AlienShip extends MovieClip {

        private var laserBeam:CannonBeam;

        public function AlienShip(){
            trace("create new alien ship");
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, enterFrameHandler );
        }

        private function enterFrameHandler(event : Event) : void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, enterFrameHandler);
        }

        public function destroySelf():void{
            parent.removeChild(this);
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enemyLoop);
        }

        public function hasCollided(otherObject:MovieClip):Boolean{
            return this.hitTestObject(otherObject);
        }

    }
```

Here is my main document class on stage where I instantiate all my base class alien objects as follow

public class RaidersMain extends MovieClip {

```
private var alienOne:AlienShip;
private var alienTwo:AlienShip;
private var alienThree:AlienShip;
private var alienFour:AlienShip;
private var alienShipArray:Array = new Array();

public function RaidersMain(){
    initGameElements();
}

    public function initGameElements():void{

            alienOne = new AlienShip();
    stage.addChild(alienOne);
    alienTwo = new  AlienShip();
    stage.addChild(alienTwo);
    alienThree = new  AlienShip();
    stage.addChild(alienThree);
    alienFour = new  AlienShip();
    stage.addChild(alienFour);
    alienShipArray.push(alienOne);
    alienShipArray.push(alienTwo);
    alienShipArray.push(alienThree);
    alienShipArray.push(alienFour);

        cann = new CannonBeam();
        stage.addChild(cann);

        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
  }

  private function loop(event : Event) : void {
      checkForBeamAlienCollision();
  }

  private function checkForBeamAlienCollision() : void {
        for(var i = 0; i < alienShipArray.length; i++){
            var currentShip:AlienShip = alienShipArray[i];

            if(currentShip.hasCollided(cann)){
                currentShip.destroySelf();
                alienShipArray.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
   }
```

But in the for loop it destroys all the aliens and not just the specific ship that the beam collides with in the for loop. What am I doing wrong? How do I correct the design of the aliens structure?

Comment: For testing purposes, in your main document, change `if(aliens.hasCollided(cann)` to `if (aliens.hitTestObject(cann)`. Does that fix the issue?

Comment: You don't need the AlienOne, AlienTwo and other class. If the class only extends Alien, it's useless.

`alienShipArray.push(new AlienShip());`

Comment: @Nambew - I assume he's planning to add more functions to them later. If not, then you're right, he should just use the base class instead.

Comment: Thanks guys. So I removed all the base classes for the aliens as you suggested. I changed my code and edited my first post. Now all my alienships are just one class objects. But still it is the same problem. Inside my for loop when the beam collides with alien ships, all of the ships get destroyed at once whenever the beam hits with one of the ships.

Comment: What is the content of the DestroySelf() method ?

Comment: Please check my first post again. I have edited and put the DestroySelf method. Also I have changed the for loop logic where the alienships get destroyed but with no success.

Comment: Alrite the code works fine if the Aliens are far apart from each other. But if one or two aliens are close to each other, both of them get destroyed. I supposed it is problem with the hitTestObject and not my logic. Is there a better way to detect collision based on pixel perfection?

Comment: I use (http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/2009/02/10/avoider-game-tutorial-6/) (use control-F to find "Using this is very simple"). It's not perfect, and it's more CPU demanding than the default hitTestObject, but that's the price you pay for perfect collision.

Comment: You also have a problem in your collision checking cycle. Here is a hint: var a:Array = [1, 2, 2, 4, 5];
 for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
  if(a[i] == 2) a.splice(i, 1);
 }
 trace(a); //traces 1,2,4,5 -> why is there a 2? cos you are not modifying the 'i' after adjusting the array length with splice